# Uniqueness of the Neumann problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, boundary-value-problem

The background of this problem is as follows:

An infinite straight metal rod of constant thermal conductivity $k$ has cross-section that is a
path-connected region S bounded by a simple closed curve $C$. 
The temperature $T(x, y)$ in each cross-section satisfies Poisson’s equation

$−k(\frac{∂^2T}{∂^2x}+\frac{∂^2T}{∂^2y})$=$Q(x,y)$

with Newton’s law of cooling giving the boundary condition
$−k\frac{∂T}{∂n} = h (T − T_a)$ for $(x, y) \in C$,
where Q is the given volumetric heat source, $h$ is the constant heat transfer coefficient, $T_a$ is the
constant ambienttemperature and $\frac{∂T}{∂n}$ denotes the outward normal derivative of $T$ on $C$.

My issue is that I am asked to prove that there is 'at most' one solution when $h>0$.  I understand the proof for uniqueness up to a constant of this problem, however, I don't understand how this idea can be extended to show that there is at most one solution when $h>0$.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that this is **not** the Neumann problem, but rather a Robin-type problem.  This is due to the fact that both $\partial T / \partial n$ and $T$ appear in the boundary condition.  If it were Neumann, it would only involve $\partial T / \partial N$, and if it were Dirichlet it would only involve $T$.  Robin is a linear combination of the Dirichlet and Neumann.

If you had two solutions $T_1, T_2$, then you could subtract one from the other to see that $T = T_1 - T_2$ solves
$$
-k\left( \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} \right) =0 \text{ in } C
$$
with the boundary condition
$$
-k \frac{\partial T}{\partial n} = h T.
$$
Here's a hint on how to finish: using this, you can mimic the proof you know for the Neumann case.